# Is there a way to clear gud's (gdb's) *input/output* buffer for a re-run?

Tags: emacs, gdb, gud

I'm recently started to use emacs gdb debugger but I can't find a way to clear *input/output* buffer for a re-run. emacs simply prints the output after the previous one!

Comment: Random guess: `M-x erase-buffer` might work.

Comment: @legoscia It works, thanks. I have to write a wrapper to do the work behind the scenes based on `(buffer-name)` or something.

Comment: If you come up with something useful, post it as an answer here :)

Answer (score 1):

The function is `(comint-clear-buffer)` bounded to `C-c M-o`, defined in `gdb-inferior-io-mode-map`.

(Old question, but first Google result.)

Comment: So `(comint-clear-buffer)` works well when the relevant pane is selected in gud's gdb-many-windows mode, how do I programatically select the `*input/output of name-of-my-executable-being-debugged*`?

Comment: You can use `(switch-to-buffer "*input/output of name-of-my-executable-being-debugged*")`.

Comment: Right, but how do I get the name of the executable?

Comment: Is it always the same name? If not, you might need to manipulate the string or use a wildcard to get any buffer with that name. Maybe [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28935/checking-if-there-exists-a-buffer-whose-name-starting-with-a-particular-string) can help.